# Stretch a distribution function based on new max and min

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, statistics

Thanks in advance for the help on this one,

I have a distribution of data that I have sorted that includes nans [-20, -19.9 ..... nan, nan] I would like to match the same shape of the distribution function but with new max and mins with the same number of nans. In my case right now I have my new min and a new max [-52, -51.5 .... nan, nan] but can only make a linear interpolation. Id like to have the same shape as the other set of data/plot shown below.

[image]

Any way I can do this? I tried some interpolation methods with taking the nans out but it didnt seem to work.

Thank again!

Comment: If you don't want to use a linear interpolation, then what do you mean exactly by "match the same shape?"  What does that mean mathematically?  Do you have a formula for equating two distributions having different minimum and maximum?  If you don't know an algorithm, you can't write a program, whether in Python or any other language.

Comment: I think that if you want to have the same shape the only way is a linear interpolation, other ways of interpolation will change this shape.. how wouldnt linear work?

Comment: I guess I was having trouble with the linear interpolation function not being able to predict what I was expecting. I was hoping to get a similar shape to the set of data that is shown above but rather got  something that had the min and max that I wanted but was a straight line from -50 to -1 then a plateau from -1 to 5. Maybe I need to rethink what I am doing?